# Present perfect tense with the verb 'is'

Tags: verbs, past-participles, be

I would like to know how to use the verb *to be* and its past participle.

For example:

> The rain is gone.

Is *is* present perfect tense here?

Comment: Typically ["perfect constructions"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/230) are those which contain the perfect auxiliary *have*.

Answer (score 3):

In modern English, the auxiliary verb  for forming the present perfect is always *to have*.
A typical present perfect clause thus consists of the  subject, the auxiliary *have/has*, 
and the  past participle  (third form) of the main verb. Examples:

- I **have eaten** some food.
- You **have gone** to school.
- He **has** already **arrived** in Catalonia.
- He **has had** child after child... ( *The Mask of Anarchy* , Percy Shelley)
- Lovely tales that we **have heard or read**... ( *Endymion (poem)* , John Keats)

Early Modern English used both *to have* and *to be* as perfect auxiliaries.
Examples of the second can be found in older texts:

- Madam, the Lady Valeria **is come** to visit you. (*The Tragedy of Coriolanus* , Shakespeare)
- Vext the dim sea: I **am become** a name... ( *Ulysses* , Tennyson)
- Pillars **are fallen** at thy feet... (*Marius amid the Ruins of Carthage*,  Lydia Maria Child)
- I **am come** in sorrow. (*Lord Jim*, Conrad)

  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect

Answer (score 2):

Nope. That is not present perfect tense. What you have there is a simple sentence whose verb "is" is in the present tense.

A present perfect tense follows the format:

> has/have + past participle of the verb

eg. *She has arrived*

You can use the present perfect tense when you want to convey an action completed in the past, or extends to the present:

For example:

> I have run 4 miles.

This means that you started running sometime in the past and at the moment you speak, you are 4 miles away from your starting point. You are also conveying that you are still running.

> I have studied French

This one means that at some time in the past, you took French courses and finished them.

Also when you want to use the verb "to be" + the past participle, the past participle acts as a predicate adjective. See usage of participles: http://www.slu.edu/colleges/AS/languages/classical/latin/tchmat/grammar/whprax/w23pplex.html

Edited: Thanks to @tchrist for making me remember of an old usage of the word "to be" in present perfect". I am actually not aware of that structure so I did a little googling and it lead me to this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtZ0V5QyJPI

Comment: *“Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.”*  —Robert Oppenheimer

Comment: Oh my God, I almost have forgotten! Your comment reminded me of "Joy to the world the Lord *is* come". I guess such is an older kind of usage.....

Comment: How do you account for Lincoln's ‘We are met on a great battle-field of that war’?