# "We are finished" vs. "We have finished"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-participles, auxiliary-verbs, perfect-aspect

Is "*we are finished*" grammatically correct? I thought it would be more correct to say "*We have finished*".

Comment: Related: [We're finished vs We're done](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218345), [Which is correct: “I’m done” or “I have finished”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150661)

Answer (score 6):

Saying *I/we are finished* implies that the person in question is in a state of being finished with some task. It is referring to the person and not specifically the task.

*I/we have finished* refers to the task itself being finished or complete, and perhaps the person has moved on to another task or is waiting for something to occur.

Comment: "I/we are finished" could also mean that "I/we" are doomed in the sense of life finishing.

Comment: yes, but that seems to be outside the context of the question as that answer was already posted and not accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in meaning, at least in idiomatic usage.

*We have finished* indicates that a task is complete.  We have no more to do.

*We are finished* is often used to convey a feeling such as *we are doomed* or *we have lost*.  There is nothing more that we are able to do.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If I want to indicate I've finished a task right at the moment at which I've finished it, I generally say *I am finished*.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou You might, but that would be distinctly unusual. Chenmunka's answer is correct that you would proclaiming your doom.

Comment: There are two constructions using _be_ here. 'The window was broken' might be describing an event ('broken' past participle) or state ('broken' participial adjective). There is still [the odd lingering usage of the perfect formed using _be_ as the auxiliary](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142897/present-perfect-tense-with-the-verb-is/144580#144580).

Comment: It may be a British vs American usage thing @Andrew.  I've never heard someone say *I have finished* to let someone know that he's finished.  The question is *are you finished?* and the answer is *yes; I am finished*.

Comment: Aha. Yes; quite probably, @George. BrE might possibly ask "Are you finished?" but the answer always uses *have*.

Comment: @George: in AmE, at least, you usually wouldn't say *"I have finished"* but *"I've finished"*. Although *"I'm finished"* sounds more common to me.

Comment: That's what I'm saying @Peter—I didn't use the contractions to be more clear; I thought it would be implied that the contractions are more frequently used.

Comment: @Andrew I've certainly heard "I'm finished here" more often than "I've finished here" (around Manchester). "I'm finished." is also not too uncommon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "I'm finished **here**" is different.

Comment: I hear "I'm done" or "I've finished".  Although "I'm finished here" or "I'm finished with this" are quite common.  "I'm finished" on its own may be a US usage but I can't say I hear it very often.

Comment: The [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ve+not+finished%2CI%27m+not+finished&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ve%20not%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20not%20finished%3B%2Cc0) for "I've not finished" and "I'm not finished" seem to show that the trends are towards favouring the latter, even (since 1960) in British English. The trends persist when a 'with' is tacked on to disambiguate more precisely.

Comment: It changes again when you indicate what you are finished [with](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition). *I am finished with the project* vs *I have finished the project*.

Comment: @SrJoven How do you get a Google Ngram for "I am finished with the project"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Omit pronoun? *am finished with the,have finished with the,have finished the*